# Selection of template value dynamically in gsp in Grails

Tags: grails

I have one select box which populates two different templates in my gsp. In both the templates I have many common fields. The problem is when I try to select and access the values of second template with jQuery, it is still taking values of 1st template for selection box.

My templates are

```
<div id="sdhltmpl" style="display: non<tmpl:SdhAddCon /></div>
<div id="wdmtmpl" style="display: none;"><tmpl:WdmAddCon /></div>
```

For both the templates I have similar columns with similar signature.e.g.

```
<input type="text"  alt="../User/LocationSearch" value="${loca}"
name="LocASearch" id="loca"/>
```

If WdmAddCon template is populated for form entry according to selection in dropdown,still it is taking values of SdhAddCon.

My access mechanism for field access is:

```
var loca=$('#loca').val();
```

Accessing by id irrespective of template reference which I do not know how to do.

Comment: In addition to that,I can catch selection value and corresponding template in javasctipt.But,after that how to access the fields specific to that template,that I am confused.

Comment: Or else if somebody can help me in suggesting how to populate different table by ID which are there in one template,so that it would solve the problem. I am doing for showing the template::                                                               $('#sdhtmpl').css("display","block"); I have two tables with different ID in that template.If I can access one of those table with conjuction with tmpl,it would be helpful and reduce the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you generating multiple DOM elements with the same ID value (e.g. `loca`) in the final HTML? That is wrong and could indicate why your Javascript is not working as expected. Try prefixing your IDs, e.g. `id="sdh-loca"` in one template call and `id="wdm-loca"` in the other. Then modify your Javascript accordingly.